# Wordpress redirect when clicked on post

Tags: wordpress, redirect, custom-wordpress-pages

***This is what I have / trying to achieve:***

1. I have some posts.
2. When someone clicks on the post i do not want it to be opened.
3. Instead, I want that the user would be redirected to url that is associated with the post (url points to external apis).

***Example, I have post:***

1. Title - 'ABC'
2. Subtitle - 'ABCABC'
3. Text - 'AAAAAABBBBBCCCC'
4. (Trying to achive) Redirect url - 'http://test.com/123'

When user clicks on my 'ABC' post I would like him to be redirected to a corresponding url - 'http://test.com/123'.

Is there a plugin for that or maybe I could use some PHP code / DB modifications for that? Examples and suggestions are welcome!

*P.S. I want the redirection to happen on every single post.*

*P.P.S. It is not suitable for me to redirect to the same constant url.*

*P.P.P.S. I really haven't found any good solutions on the web.*

Answer (score 3):

There's a few plugins that can do what you're looking for.

One I wrote a while ago that gives you the option to bring the external content into your site -or- 301 redirect to it: [Content Mask](https://wordpress.org/plugins/content-mask/)

One that works similarly, but just redirects: [Page Links To](https://wordpress.org/plugins/page-links-to/)

Or one that lets you handle it without going into each post: [Simple 301 Redirects](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-301-redirects/).

Alternatively, you could set a [Custom Field](https://wordpress.org/support/article/custom-fields/) on your posts with the external URL. Then, check if that value is set, and if so, redirect to the external URL, something like the following:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_externally' );
function redirect_externally(){
    $redirect = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'redirect_to_here', true );

    if( $redirect ){
        wp_redirect( $redirect );
    }
}
```